# TouchesBegan not firing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, swift2

My story board looks something like this:

```
Controller
    top/bottom layout guide
    view
        UIview
            UIButton
        UIImageView
```

And my touch function this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touched")
}
```

My print is getting logged when I touch everywhere on the screen except for where the button is located.

The UIImageView takes up the entire screen and the button is just a 50x50 px square in the middle. Although all I can see is the image when I click on-top of where the button is nothing gets fired. Clicking everywhere else fires the event properly

Comment: That's not how you set up a `UIButton`. - you need to create a method marked with `@IBAction` e.g. `@IBAction func buttonAction(sender:AnyObject!) { ... }` and connect it to the 'touch up inside' action on the button in your storyboard.  Try doing a few basic tutorials for further guidance -[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) has some good ones

Comment: But shouldn't the button be irrelevant because it is underneath the uiimageview. How come it is affecting the touchesbegan of the view

Comment: `UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false` by default, unlike normal UI views, so the touch is passing through it and registering on the underlying view, but the button has `userInteractionEnabled` set to true, but no action, so it is intercepting the touch and doing nothing with it, but blocking the `-touchesBegan:` on the view beneath

Comment: ahh I see, thank you that's what I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if elements user interaction enable property is true. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure to make the UIButton to the appropriate Method via @IBAction. In the main.storyboard screen, you can right-click or options-click on the UIButton and drag it to the appropriate class.